# Background static in earphones

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, realtek

Just installed Ubuntu (new user) and there's this persistent static hiss in the background of my earphones. I've tried disabling loopback and that in alsamixer but to no avail.

I thought it might be because I don't have the Realtek HD Audio driver installed (using ALC1150) but it gives errors when I try compiling the files.

Anyone know what I can do with this?

Comment: How do you know its not a hardware issue?

Comment: I have Windows 10 on the machine also, and it works flawlessly on that.